# ASP.NET - Page Postbacks and event handling

Tags: asp.net, events

Can anyone suggest me good reading materials on the internals of how ASP.NET handles page postback and events?

-Justin Samuel.

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely read [Microsoft's primer on the ASP.NET page lifecycle.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)  Knowing the page lifecycle well will save you many headaches!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [How postback works in ASP.NET](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18):

> In this article, we will take a closer
>   look at how ASP.NET pages post back to
>   themselves, and how to customize this
>   feature in our web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read these articles:

- https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1045191.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_events.asp
- http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/15190-ASP-NET-Page-Life-Cycle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are just learning ASP.NET, check out ASP.NET MVC as an alternative which will make a lot more sense coming from other web platforms and doesn't have the added abstraction of events, state, and postbacks which http wasn't exactly designed to have.